# How to create a variable alias on a array of arrays in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Say I have the following array of arrays of floats and a selector index:

```
const float array[][3] = {  
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
};

/// The one that select one of the five arrays
int selector = 0;
```

To streamline my code, I'd like to declare an array that points to the current array selector to further use it as a simple array of float, as follows:

```cpp
/// A shortcut to the current selection
const float currentArray[] = array[selector];

for (int i = 0; i<3: i++) {
   process(currentArray[iI]);
}
```

As this does not compile (`initialization expected with {}`), how could I declare my current-array alias?

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`? Then you can pass in `const std::vector<float>&`.

Comment: Hint: `const float* current = array[selector]`, or even better, `auto& current = array[selector]`.

Comment: Oh my… it makes it.

Comment: This is because `float x[] =` is a declaration of a local copy of something, like you did in your original `array` initialization.

Comment: Why do you show 5 arrays of an array of 3 ints but only loop through the first 3 in your example?

Comment: @doug I am looping through the vector itself. The selector variable is the index of the vector I should iterate  through.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you need type alias for your `currentArray`.

In this case you can do the following:

```
const float array[][3] = {
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
    {0, 1, 2,},
};

/// The one that select one of the five arrays
int selector = 0;

using InnerArrayT = const float (&)[3];

InnerArrayT currentArray = array[selector];

for (int i = 0; i<3: i++) {
   process(currentArray[i]);
}
```

Or as @tadman has pointed out you can use `auto &` but be careful because if you use just `auto`(without `&`) then `currentArray` type will be `const float *` instead of `const float (&)[3]`.